# Import external JS scripts in Google Colab html

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-colaboratory

I am having a hard time importing my custom external JS files to Google Colab. I work with html + js, following this workflow:

1 / imports

```
from IPython.display import HTML, SVG
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
```

2 / mount drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

3 / html

```
@register_cell_magic
def dojs(line, src):
  return HTML(f"""
  <canvas id="renderCanvas" touch-action="none" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas> 
  <script src="content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/files/testJavascript.js"></script>
  <script>
  {src} 
  </script>
  """)
```

4 / js

```
%%dojs
//...trying to use functions from testJavascript.js
```

Maybe it's really trivial how to do this but I'm new at Colab. I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()".

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your JS file in here:

`/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/google.colab/`

Then it can be access through the path

`/nbextensions/google.colab/`

In your case, you need to copy your js file there:

```
!cp /content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/files/testJavascript.js \
    /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/google.colab/
```

Then change `dojs()` to be

```
@register_cell_magic
def dojs(line, src):
  return HTML(f"""
  <canvas id="renderCanvas" touch-action="none" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas> 
  <script src="/nbextensions/google.colab/testJavascript.js"></script>
  <script>
  {src} 
  </script>
  """)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines like `script src="content/drive...` won't work. The reason is that your Drive files are present on the backend VM executing your code. But, using a `<script>` tag is going to be resolved by your browser against the current base origin, which is `colab.research.google.com`, which doesn't serve your Drive files.

There are some recipes for serving local files in the advanced outputs example here:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=R8ZvCXC5A0wT